# Finding the general formula for the sum of the first n terms.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

So I'm trying to solve this practice problem I found on the internet. [PracticeProblemLink](https://query.libretexts.org/Community_Gallery/WeBWorK_Assessments/Calculus_-_single_variable/Infinite_sequences_and_series/Partial_sums/Q_34.pg)

$$\displaystyle{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2e^{-n}} }$$

The part I'm stuck on is this: *The general formula for the sum of the first n terms is Sn=[____]*

I know that the common ratio is $$e^{-1}$$ and that the first term is $$2$$

And the formula for the nth term is $$S_n= \frac{a (1-r^n)}{(1-r)} $$

So I used this for this problem, getting the fraction $$ \frac{2(1-( e^{-n} )) }{(1-e^{-1})} $$

When I entered this into the problem it said I was incorrect. Am I missing something in the question?

Comment: @Gary The question (below the infinite series) is asking for the sum of the first $n$ terms.

Comment: Yes, but I just need a formula for the first n terms.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $r^{n+1}$ in the sum formula rather than $r^n$?

Comment: $a+ar+ ar^2 + \cdots + ar^n = a \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ is the sum of the first $n+1$ terms, while $a+ar+ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{n-1} = a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms. So I think your work is correct for "sum of the first $n$ terms", but note that some people define $S_n$ to be the first expression (sum of the first $n+1$ terms) instead of the second expression (sum of the first $n$ terms).

Comment: Ah yes. I was copying it wrong. Thank you so much @Gary and @angryavian!

Comment: @angryavian Yes. The phrasing on the website is incorrect. By $S_n$ they mean the sum up to the term with index $n$, but that means that we sum the first $n+1$ terms.

Comment: @KayleeDalton You were technically correct given the question that was asked. The website's answer was wrong (equivalently, their question was poorly worded for their intended answer).

Comment: Yeah. I was going mad trying to figure out what was wrong, you're right that it was poorly worded. They are free practice problems after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is correct for the sum of the first $n$ terms (from $0$ to $n-1$):
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B2Exp%5B-k%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D

Aside: it is a confusing choice to use $n$ as the summation index and then ask for the sum of the first $n$ terms.